# Unable to pass a variable to a procedure using upvar in Tcl

Tags: tcl, proc-object, upvar

I need a procedure that will be able to access, read and change a variable from the namespace of the caller. The variable is called `_current_selection`. I have tried to do it using `upvar` in several different ways, but nothing worked. (I've written small test proc just to test the `upvar` mechanism). Here are my attempts:

---

call to proc:

```
select_shape $this _current_selection
```

proc:

```
proc select_shape {main_gui var_name} {
    upvar  $var_name curr_sel
    puts " previously changed:  $curr_sel"
    set curr_sel [$curr_sel + 1]
}
```

---

For my second attempt:

call to proc:

```
select_shape $this
```

proc:

```
proc select_shape {main_gui} {
    upvar  _current_selection curr_sel
    puts " previously changed:  $curr_sel"
    set curr_sel [$curr_sel + 1]
}
```

---

In all the attempts, once it reaches this area in the code it says `can't read "curr_sel": no such variable`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The call for the function is made from a `bind` command:

```
$this/zinc bind current <Button-1> [list select_shape $this _current_selection]
```

at start I thought that it doesn't matter. but maybe It does.

Comment: I see `$this` variable. Do you use incrTcl classes? They are not the same as namespaces.

Comment: @GrAnd: Agreed. The use of `upvar` itself seems OK. Something else is going on; a _really_ significant detail is missing.

Comment: @Ilya: You could try reporting what `info loaded` returns; most object systems are dynamically-loaded packages implemented in C, so they can be introspected for easily.

Comment: The call for the function is inside a bind command:
`$this/zinc bind current <Button-1> [list select_shape $this _current_selection]`

Comment: It's more valuable to know from _where_ it's called. Is the `_current_selection` defined/accessible in that scope? Is that line located in namespace proc or class proc?

Comment: @GrAnd the `_current_selection` is defined in namespace proc (I think), When I pass it to the function as `$_current_selection`, it transfers it's value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `bind` commands operate in the global namespace, so that's where the variable is expected to be found. This might work:

```
$this/zinc bind current <Button-1> \
    [list select_shape $this [namespace current]::_current_selection]
```

Answer (score 3):

for upvar to work the variable must exist in the scope that you are calling it in.  consider the following:

```
proc t {varName} {
   upvar $varName var
   puts $var
}

#set x 1
t x
```

If you run it as it is you'll get the error you are reporting, uncomment the *set x 1* line and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I've tried to cover the most variants of changing variables from other namespace. It 100% works for me. Maybe it will help.

```
proc select_shape {main_gui var_name} {
    upvar  $var_name curr_sel
    puts " previously changed:  $curr_sel"
    incr curr_sel
}

namespace eval N {
  variable _current_selection 1
  variable this "some_value"

  proc testN1 {} {
    variable _current_selection
    variable this
    select_shape $this _current_selection
    puts " new: $_current_selection"
  }

  # using absolute namespace name
  proc testN2 {} {
    select_shape [set [namespace current]::this] [namespace current]::_current_selection
    puts " new: [set [namespace current]::_current_selection]"
  }

  select_shape $this _current_selection
  puts " new: $_current_selection"
}

N::testN1
N::testN2

#-------------------------------------
# Example with Itcl class
package require Itcl

itcl::class C {
  private variable _current_selection 10

  public method testC {} {
    select_shape $this [itcl::scope _current_selection]
    puts " new: $_current_selection"
  }
}

set c [C #auto]
$c testC
```